# Is running in zoomed mode ground for rejection

Tags: ios, iphone

Does Apple reject submitted apps because they run in zoomed mode on some iOS devices? I'm asking this question because the app that I am developing doesn't have images for iPhone 6 and 6 Plus's resolutions therefore the app has no other choice than to run using zoomed mode. Is anyone familiar with this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry. Apple will not reject your application. But, it will work in scaled mode in iPhone 6 / 6+.